# Goodness-of-fit test for single but high-dimensional datum

Tags: goodness-of-fit, high-dimensional

Are there any goodness-of-fit tests for samples consisting of only one datum that is high-dimensional?
Usually, G-o-F tests are run using samples with multiple datums, each having a single dimension.

I suppose this problem could also be considered as having a single, high-dimensional datum, and testing the goodness-of-fit against a probability distribution with the same dimensionality.

Bonus question: How does the concept of typicality relate to this?